# Stacking two videos with a precise time offset

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to use FFmpeg to produce a stereoscopic side-by-side video (Full 3D SBS) from a left-right pair of videos.

If the two source videos were perfectly in sync, I could use:

```
ffmpeg -i left.mp4 -i right.mp4 -filter_complex hstack stereo.mp4
```

Unfortunately, the cameras were not synchronized and I determined that I need to trim the first 30 frames or 1.0 second from the left video to align it with the right one.

Referring to the FFmpeg wiki on [Seeking](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Seeking), I could either use fast input seeking with `-ss 1 -i left.mp4`, or accurate output seeking with `-i left.mp4 -ss 1`. I want accurate seeking, but unfortunately `-i left.mp4 -ss 1 -i right.mp4` doesn't work the way I'd hope.

How can I accurately skip the first second of `left.mp4` while starting from the beginning of `right.mp4`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the [`tpad` filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#tpad) in conjunction with `hstack` to *delay* the right side 30 frames, rather than *trim* the left side:

```
ffmpeg -i left.mp4 -i right.mp4 -filter_complex \
    "[0:v]null [left]; \
     [1:v]tpad=30:start_mode=add [right]; \
     [left][right]hstack" \
    stereo.mp4
```

(However without electronically synchronized shutters, I found that the frame alignment does drift over time by quite a lot.)